# Как правильно ставить ударение?

Tags: фонетика

Интересует слово "тирамису". Насколько мне известно, это слово итальянского происхождения, но тогда ударение должно стоять на предпоследнем слоге, то есть "тирамИсу", но все говорят "тирамисУ". Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итальянском ударение как раз на последнем слоге. Таких слов в итальянском немного, но они есть - и ударение в них всегда обозначается на письме.
**Тирамису (итал. Tiramisù, дословно — «вознеси меня»).**

Другое дело, что место ударения в языке-источнике не всегда соответствует ему в языке-мишени. Но в нашем случае тут как раз всё в порядке.

Answer (score 0):

ТирамисУ - правильно. А ударение в итальянском языке может быть на любом гласном из четырех конечных.